# WooCommerce error when removing billing fields: "Please enter an address to continue."

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've removed billing fields on the WooCommerce checkout page by adding the following lines to `functions.php`:

```
add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields", "remove_billing_fields");
function remove_billing_fields($fields) {
    unset($fields["billing"]["billing_first_name"]);
    unset($fields["billing"]["billing_last_name"]);
    unset($fields["billing"]["billing_company"]);
    unset($fields["billing"]["billing_address_1"]);
    unset($fields["billing"]["billing_address_2"]);
    unset($fields["billing"]["billing_city"]);
    unset($fields["billing"]["billing_postcode"]);
    unset($fields["billing"]["billing_country"]);
    unset($fields["billing"]["billing_state"]);
    unset($fields["billing"]["billing_email"]);
    unset($fields["billing"]["billing_phone"]);
    return $fields;
}
```

This does remove the billing fields and leaves the shipping fields in-tact, as desired. However, now I get an error on checkout:

```
Please enter an address to continue.
```

However, all shipping fields are filled out. The request is being sent via AJAX (`/shop/checkout?wc-ajax=checkout`). Upon inspecting the request, I see the following fields are being sent:

```
billing_email:john@example.com
shipping_first_name:John
shipping_last_name:Doe
shipping_address_1:123 Easy St
shipping_address_2:
shipping_country:US
shipping_state:NY
shipping_city:New York
shipping_postcode:12345
billing_phone:123-456-7890
payment_method:stripe
wc-stripe-payment-token:abc123
_wpnonce:abc123
_wp_http_referer:/shop/checkout
```

Note that the request does go through when billing fields are set, so I believe everything else is set up correctly. Any ideas why this error is being thrown?

Comment: I have make some test with your code on WooCommerce version 3.12 and I don't get this problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found that although I can hide the `billing_country` field, it is required in order to calculate taxes and shipping, even if WooCommerce is configured to use the shipping fields by default.

Comment: This comment is right. It prevent me from big hustle thanks, David